# Sorting range values

Tags: ruby, sorting

I want to sort an array of strings representing numerical ranges like the following:

```
b = ["0-5", "100-250", "5-25", "50-100", "250-500", "25-50"]
```

Using the `sort` method I get:

```
b.sort 
# => ["0-5", "100-250", "25-50", "250-500", "5-25", "50-100"]
```

I want it like this instead:

```
["0-5, "5-25", "25-50", "50-100", "100-250", "250-500"]
```

Comment: Have you tried converting those strings to actual ranges and sort those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b.sort_by { |a| a.split('-').first.to_i }

=> ["0-5", "5-25", "25-50", "50-100", "100-250", "250-500"]
```

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
b.sort_by { |r| r.split('-').map(&:to_i) }
# => ["0-5", "5-25", "25-50", "50-100", "100-250", "250-500"]
```

This solution takes each item (`"0-5"`) splits it to two items (`["0", "5"]`), and converts them to integers (`[0, 5]`). Now sort sorts by the array (first item first, and the second as a tie-breaker).

Answer (score 5):

```
b.sort_by(&:to_i)
  #=> ["0-5", "5-25", "25-50", "50-100", "100-250", "250-500"]
```

because

```
"25-50".to_i #=> 25
```